# My OnCanExecute event happens repeatedly

Tags: wpf, xaml

I've got a `TextBox` in `xaml` that I want to be validated using the `CanExecute` option of the commands. Here I have the `xaml`:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <RoutedUICommand x:Key="CloseCommand" Text=""/>
    <RoutedUICommand x:Key="NextCommand" Text=""/>
    <RoutedUICommand x:Key="BackCommand" Text=""/>
</UserControl.Resources>

<UserControl.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="{StaticResource CloseCommand}" Executed="Close" />
    <CommandBinding Command="{StaticResource NextCommand}" Executed="Next" CanExecute="OnCanExecute" />
    <CommandBinding Command="{StaticResource BackCommand}" Executed="Back" />
</UserControl.CommandBindings>
```

These are the `CommandBindings` that are called, where the `Next` command is tied to a `CanExecute` restriction. The button looks like this:

```
<Button 
    DockPanel.Dock="Right"
    Name="ButtonNext"
    Margin="0,0,15,0"
    Style="{DynamicResource NextButton}"
    Command="{StaticResource NextCommand}">
 </Button>
```

And the `.cs` for the validation:

```
private void OnCanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    e.CanExecute = ValidateFields();
}
```

Where the `ValidateFields()` method looks like this:

```
 public bool ValidateFields()
 {
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(AutoCompleteBox.Text)) return false;
    return IsValid(MyTextBox);
 }
```

So my `OnCanExecute` is tied to a `TextBox` validation. But I've got a problem. Even if a leave the Window where this code is written, I noticed that this `OnCanExecute` is still being called.

Why is this? Why my `OnCanExecute` is being called even if it's not visible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NextCommand` is a `RoutedCommand`.
If you have a look at the [implementation](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationCore/Core/CSharp/System/Windows/Input/Command/RoutedCommand.cs,126), you'll notice that `CanExecuteChanged` is fired whenever `CommandManager.RequerySuggested` is fired.
This will be in many circumstances. I don't know exactly but it may be as often as the mouse moves or a key is pressed (or other user interactions)!

You could add a counter variable in your Eventhandler could to have a look how often this happens.
If your RoutedCommand.CanExecute depends on something from "code-behind" and you don't move the mouse, press a key or some other user interaction, the CanExecuteChanged may not fire although it should.

You can test this if you make your CanExecute depend on a periodically switching bool.

Comment: I realized that happens whenever an event is fired... Thanks, it was claryfing!